# BAT File Help - If file is below xKB, delete and replace with xFile

Tags: xml, batch-file

I would like to create a batch file to delete a specific file called Config.xml but only if it is less than 9KB, and replace it with another file called Config.bak.

I realise in order to replace Config.xml, with Config.bak, Config.bak needs to be renamed to Config.xml but only after the original Config.xml has been deleted (as a result of it being less than 9KB).

Config.bak and Config.xml exist within the same directory:
\PDC\Users\%Username%\Application Data\Zoiper

Currently I have this:

```
pushd "\\PDC\Users\%Username%\Application Data\Zoiper"
for %%j in (*config.xml) do if %%~zj lss 9000 del "%%~j"
popd
pause
```

This works to delete Config.xml if it is less than 9KB, but I haven't any idea how to do the rest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pushd "\\PDC\Users\%Username%\Application Data\Zoiper"
for %%j in (*config.xml) do (
 if %%~zj lss 9000 ( 
   rem del "%%~j"
   copy /y Config.bak Config.xml
  )
)
popd
pause
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked perfectly. I would also like for this batch file to restart a program that may or may not be running called Zoiper.exe.
Is it possible to add this into this batch?

Comment: @LetsTorque - you can easy kill the prorgam with `taskkill /im zoiper* /f` .To start it you'll need its location